# Visit and order sequence for multiple imputation in mice r

Tags: missing-data, multiple-imputation, mice

I want to use the R package MICE for Multiple Imputation and I have a question concerning the order of my dataset - regarding the order of my variables on the one hand and the order of my cases on the other hand.

1. Sequence of variables:
   Is it necessary to define a certain sequence of the variables for a dataset like the chronological order of questions in a survey or the percentage of missingness?
   Depending on the sequence of the dataset I will receive different but similar results, so I was wondering whether I should define a certain variable order which is stringent and rational.
   Should there be a mathematical methodology to do so or would it be rather a "content decision" because there is no "wrong" or "false"?

```
set.seed(123)
library(mice)
data_org <- nhanes
# pmm used by default
imp <- mice(data_org, m = 10)
fit <- with(data = imp, expr = lm(bmi ~ age))
summary(pool(fit))
#      term estimate std.error statistic       df      p.value
# 1 (Intercept) 30.00353 1.9492757 15.392141 16.24020 4.140762e-11
# 2         age -1.99814 0.9777381 -2.043635 17.61059 5.624394e-02

# change visitSequence
imp <- mice(data_org, m = 10, visitSequence = "monotone")
fit <- with(data = imp, expr = lm(bmi ~ age))
summary(pool(fit))
#         term  estimate std.error statistic       df      p.value
# 1 (Intercept) 30.232995 1.9132390  15.80200 16.08753 3.208201e-11
# 2         age -2.015338 0.9634098  -2.09188 17.25563 5.153336e-02
```

As far as I have understood van Buuren, [link](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-algoptions.html) it might have an
impact but it does not really much matter in practice.
If I receive convergence and I am able to confirm a good fit for my imputation model [link](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-diagnostics.html)
am I good to go for further analytics?

2. Sequence of cases

How is the result influenced by a different row sequence?

```
data_order <- data_org[order(data_org$bmi),]
imp_order <- mice(data_order, m = 10)
fit_order <- with(data = imp_order, expr = lm(bmi ~ age))
summary(pool(fit_order))
#     term estimate std.error statistic       df      p.value
# 1 (Intercept) 29.76087  2.171645  13.70430 13.65104 2.293383e-09
# 2         age -1.88413  1.062955  -1.77254 15.95960 9.538992e-02
# (The differences slightly increased compared to the first output above.)
```

How is the set of donors effected by a different sequence of my cases?
What I couldn't clarify for myself:
If the algorithm selects one value for case 1, is the imputed value of case 1 a possible donor for the following cases which have missing data? So if I had 100 cases: would case no. 100 (with a missing in variable A) have 99 donors because of a potential chronological imputatation process (mixture of observed and already imputed values) or is that not how it works?
In that case: would it rather make sense to have the cases with less missing values on the top of my dataset as I then would have more observed values as a basis for the imputation of the following cases with an increasing number of missings (if imputation happens case by case?)?
Or is that not a problem as the multiple imputation only picks donors from actual observed answers, so the sequence of cases is hereby irrelevant?

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any difference in estimates you are seeing can be completely explained by the fact that you are using few imputations. It often takes many more than 10 imputations for results to stabilize. In practice, the order of variables in imputation doesn't matter, especially if you have many iterations (separate from imputations) because the imputed values should converge. The order of observations does not matter at all; imputations for all units are created simultaneously and used simultaneously in all future imputations. Any differences you observe can be explained by the random number generation and the few imputations you requested. Because random numbers are generated in sequence (e.g., by using `rnorm()` internally), the order the units are in does change the imputed values, but it does so in a random way unrelated to the values of any variables (seen or unseen).